# How to hide bar labels from Google Chart Timeline

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to remove labels(c1,c2,c3,c4) from my bars.

I tried styling with: 
`timeline: {barLabelStyle: ...}` 
but nothing works for me (I thought about set font color to color of bar, but docs says ,,You can't set the color of barLabel text."

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/550wb2t0/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use --> `timeline: { showBarLabels: false }`

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Activity', 'Category', 'Start Time', 'End Time'],

    ['Sleep', 'c1',
      new Date(2014, 10, 15, 12, 30, 0, 120),
      new Date(2014, 10, 15, 14, 30, 20, 550)
    ],

    ['Eat Breakfast', 'c2',
      new Date(2014, 10, 15, 12, 30, 55),
      new Date(2014, 10, 15, 14, 31, 55)
    ],

    ['Commute Home', 'c3',
      new Date(2014, 10, 15, 12, 29, 30),
      new Date(2014, 10, 15, 14, 30, 0)
    ],
    ['Commute Home', 'c4',
      new Date(2014, 10, 15, 14, 30),
      new Date(2014, 10, 15, 18)
    ]
  ]);

  var colors = [];
  var colorMap = {
    // should contain a map of category -> color for every category
    c1: '#e63b6f',
    c2: '#19c362',
    c3: '#592df7',
    c4: '#000000'
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    colors.push(colorMap[data.getValue(i, 1)]);
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(colors));

  var options = {
    height: 450,
    colors: colors,
    timeline: { showBarLabels: false }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```